# How to run multiple instances of one GO application?

Tags: go, webserver

In python, you may have uwsgi application server run multiple instances of your application at the same time.

The problem is not about load-balancing incoming requests in which goroutines do best. You can have many goroutines run concurrently but until the main app is alive. If the app crashes no goroutines are there to process any task.

**My question is**: how we can run multiple instances of one go app at the same time?. If the problem is solved in another way by Go, what is that?

Comment: would a heaertbeat script not be good here? a simple script that checks if your important go code is still running.

Comment: i do not know any integrated toold for this, the last time i need to check if i process was a live i wrote a go script to look at all process id's and the names associated with it. if the code that needed to run was not active it would start it using the command line

Comment: Recommending third-party tools is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Most OS offer some way to ensure a service is running. On Windows, this would be a Windows Service. On Linux, process managers like systemd et al can ensure a process is restarted if it crashes. A simple shell script could do the same on any OS. If your question is more than just how to keep a service running, please edit your question to clarify your intentions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not saying it's off-topic as it relates to your situation, I'm saying it's not permitted on this site: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Adrian when a service crashes and is reloaded by OS we lose time and uptime will be less than 100%

Comment: On that instance, yes. And no matter what you do, any requests in-flight will fail when it crashes. You want to avoid crashes first and foremost, and generally you increase uptime by increasing the number of machines hosting a service, behind a load balancer, not by trying to run "spare" processes of the service on the same machine, which is unlikely to prove successful.

Comment: Python does that precisely because the language does not have anything like goroutines. You don't need to do anything special in Go to get this behavior; it's built in to net/http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have stated prior, you'll want to have various instances running to help decrease downtime. Theoretically multiple instances on the same server will prevent most of the software crashing downtime. If you're worried about hardware failure, you'll want multiple servers running with some loadbalancer/proxy handling the request. Things like nginx or haproxy will provide that.

You may also want to consider containerization for this. Containerization allows you to easily run multiple software instances of your application, and it'll be easy to ensure you have the number you want. Kubernetes and related apps will improve this reliability even further, and give you clustering.